# View not rendering when passing ajax data to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following actoin in my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ShowClient(string ClientCode)
    {
        if (ClientCode == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

        }
        ClientViewModel clientViewModel = this.clientService.FindByClientCode(ClientCode);
        if (clientViewModel == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();

        }

        return View("ShowClient", clientViewModel);
    }
```

The following ajax code is hitting the action in the controller:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Client/ShowClient",
                data: "ClientCode=" + code/*{ "ClientCode": code }*/, //First item has latest ID
                //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.length !== 0) {
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
```

And the view :

```
@model BusinessModels.ClientViewModel


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Show Client";
}

some usual html form
```

However my view is not being displayed.
When i debug the code, I can see that clientViewModel does contain data and the debug does go in my view.
Any idea why it is not displaying the view?

Maybe I can use RedirectToAction?

Comment: You need to add it to the DOM in the `success` callback. Note also it should be `return PartialView (...);`

Comment: I don't get how to do it.

Comment: `success: function (){ $('someElement').html(data); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to need to load HTML in div and need to define dataType: "HTML".

```
  $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
            url: "/Client/ShowClient",
            data: "ClientCode=" + code/*{ "ClientCode": code }*/, //First item has latest ID
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "html",
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#dialog').html(data);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        });
```

for more details please see [Working example](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Return-Partial-View-from-Controller-using-AJAX-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx)